# Add strings with spaces to value of dictionary Python(2.7) + sort

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I am reading from an input file called "id2" which is setup in this format

```
9 This
6 This Is
15 This Is The
42 This Is The Word
```

I'm trying to write a script that adds each line into its own dictionary (the number is the key and any words that follow are the value).  Currently, my code only works with strings that contain no whitespace (i.e. it will only work with the first line " 9 This " ).  The error I receive is 'ValueError: too many values to unpack'.

I also need the script to print the ' key : value ' result only (not the dictionary itself) and have it be sorted numerically.  I'm pretty sure I need dict.keys and list.sort but I'm unsure how to implement.  The following is my code thus far:

```
d = {}
with open("id2") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[int(key)] = val
print d
```

Comment: `adds each line into its own dictionary` - Are you trying to create a new dictionary for every line in the file?

Comment: In python 3.x, you can use extended iterable unpacking: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/ example: `key, *val = line.split()` Though, I know you're in Python 2 so this doesn't apply :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation addresses your issues.  Adding the maxsplits argument to `line.split()` will break the string in only one place.  The argument None will cause any continuous whitespace to be removed between the number and the string.  I added `val.rstrip()` to remove the newline that is present at the end of the line.  Then finally I sorted by key and printed each item out.

```
d = {}
with open("id2") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split(None, 1)
        d[int(key)] = val.rstrip()
for key in sorted(d):
    print key, ':', d[key]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
key, value = string.split(line, maxsplit = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
d = {}
with open("id2") as f:
    for line in f:
        lst = line.split()
        key, val = lst[0], " ".join(lst[1:])
        d[int(key)] = val
print d
```

Comment: splitting and then rejoining is unecessary...just index the string

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting a string by space (the default for `str.split`). You are trying to assign the result to 2 values, but the result is always more than 2 values for the given strings.

If the first element of the string is always a number, followed by a space, you can do:

```
key = int(line[0])
value = line[2:]
```

(there is no need to waste typing with a function call to str.split..remember that a string is a list)

To sort:

```
sorted(d)
```

But you probably want to preserve ordering after sort, so use `OrderedDict`instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d_sorted = OrderedDict(sorted(d))
```

Comment: `key = int(line[0])` will generate the wrong key when the number has more than 1 digit.